# I am facing some problem in rasa chatbot installation

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa

I have facing issue when i install rasa chatbot in my system. here is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! It is highly recommended to post relevant text information like code, errors and logs as text not images. Please edit your question and replace images with error text. It will help other users to find and answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Windows can be a tricky installation target. Most issues should be resolved if you follow the steps in [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ewIABo0OkU).

Comment: I know windows can be a tricky installation but when i install in conda root env, it's  install correctly without any error but when i create a new env, i got this problems.

Answer (score 0):

Mybe you need install wheel by`pip install wheel` first.

Comment: I installed success on my pc, win 10，after upgraded pip and pip install wheel.